# Generating the derived category with line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

The following lemma is useful and well-known:

LEMMA If $L^{\pm 1}$ is ample on proper scheme over a field $k$, then some number of powers $\mathcal{O},L,...,L^{m}$ generate the unbounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves $D(X)$ (or split generate the subcategory of perfect complexes).

QUESTION: What about a converse? Suppose that I know some number of powers of $L$ generate $D(X)$. Then can I conclude that $L^{\pm 1}$ is ample?

The best I can do so far is see that the restriction of $L$ to any integral curve 
$C$ in $X$ has non-zero degree. (Since by adjunction $\mathcal{O},L,...,L^{m}$ generates $D(C)$, but if $L$ had degree $0$ on $C$, there would be something orthogonal $\mathcal{O},L,...,L^{m}$, for instance a generic line bundle of degree $g-1$ having no cohomology.)

Something I don't know yet: does the degree of $L$ must have the same sign on all curves?
This would be useful for numerical tests of ampleness.

Note: I think that one doesn't need properness in the above lemma, but I am willing to assume it to get a converse. It makes life easier when restricting to closed subschemes.

Note 2: When saying a collection of objects generates a triangulated category with all coproducts, like $D(X)$, one usually means that you take the smallest triangulated subcategory closed under all coproducts and containing the the collection. Once you have all coproducts, then idempotents automatically split, by a standard argument called, I think, the Eilenberg swindle. If you are working with a smaller triangulated category having only finite coproducts, like perfect complexes on a scheme, then the smallest triangulated subcategory containing a collection might not be 'thick', in the sense that some idempotents might not split, so in this case one usually adds in the missing summands. To emphasize this, some people speak of 'split generation'.

Comment: I think you mean to say that these powers split-generate the derived category (otherwise, all varieties would have finite rank $K_0$ which fails already for curves).

Comment: Can you give a reference for the lemma? Thanks!

Comment: One reference would be  arXiv:0804.1163, Theorem 4.

If you are willing to assume $X$ proper, then you can give a shorter argument by replacing $L$ with some power that is both ample and globally generated, use this to get a finite morphism to some projective space, and then pull-back the usual generator $
\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \cdots \mathcal{O}(n)$ from there.


Comment: What are your assumptions on $X$? At the very least you will need irreducible...

Comment: I am happy to assume $X$ is irreducible and even integral, but why do you think the former is necessary?

Comment: I do not know much about derived categories, so this question might well be silly, but here it is anyway! Is it true that if some number of powers of $L$ generate the derived category of $X$, then for every line bundle $M$ on $X$ there is a non-zero map from some power of $L$ to $M$?

Comment: There might not be a non-zero morphism $L \rightarrow M$ or equivalently a non-zero element of $H^{0}(L^{*}\otimes M)$, but
there will always be a non-zero element of $Ext^{i}(L,M)\simeq H^{i}(L^{*} \otimes M)$. 

Comment: I meant, there will be a non-zero... for some $i$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In the case of curves, when you say that "by adjunction" you generate the derived category, what do you mean? Would it be possible to extend the statement to reducible curves? This would give you a way of making the sign of the restriction consistent. Alternatively, do you have a "simple" criterion to test if the powers of a line bundle generate the derived category?

Comment: Hi. It just occured to me that you are probably the Damiano that I know. The simple test is this: a perfect complex $E$ (in this case a sum of powers of line bundles) generates if and only if for each possibly unbounded complex $F$ of quasi-coherent sheaves, $RHom(E,F)=0$ implies $F=0$. When I spoke of adjunction, I meant for push-pull along a closed immersion $i: Z \rightarrow X$. So if $E$ generates on $X$, then $Li^{*}E$ generates on $Z$. 

Comment: Now the claim is that if $Z$ is an integral curve, then powers of a line bundle generate if and only if the degree of $L$ is non-zero. It is then enough to check this on the normalization. So suppose $L$ is of degree $0$ and argue that no number of powers can generate. To do this, I claim that for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, you can always find a divisor $D$ of degree $g-1$ so that $L^{j}(D)$ has no cohomology 
for $j \in \{0,-1,...,-m\}$, so that $RHom(\oplus L^{i}, \mathcal{O}(D))=0$ and so $\oplus L^{i}$ doesn't generate.

Comment:  To see that such a divisor exists, play around with the action of $Pic^{0}$ on $Pic^{g-1}$. I guess you need some rational points on your curve. But perhaps you can reduce to the case that your ground field is algebraically closed, or at least assume it.

Comment: Hi! I am indeed the Damiano you know, and when I read your comment, I also realized why your name sounded so familiar!

Just to make sure that I understand everything correctly: the restriction to *any* closed subvariety of *X* of a line bundle whose powers generate is again a line bundle whose powers generate (on the smaller variety), right? If what I understood is correct, then I think that the question reduces essentially to the case of surfaces.

Comment: Btw, on surfaces it is easy to construct examples of line bundles *L* having non-zero intersection with every curve and having the property that for every line bundle *M* there are $n,i$ such that $Ext^i(L^n,M)$ is non-zero. Such line bundles need not be ample, nor the dual of an ample line bundle. Would this be enough?

Comment: Yes. Restricting a generator along any closed immersion will give a generator on the subscheme. I'll have to think about your latter comment, but unfortunately will not be able to do so for about a week.
However, I am not too worried, since you would need to replace the line bundle $M$ with a possibly unbounded complex of quasi-coherents to know that you had a non-ample generator. More in about a week...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can construct a (many) counter-examples as follows. Let $X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ along a point $p_0 \in \mathbb{P}^2$. I denote by $E$ the exceptional divisor. Let $\pi : X \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ be the blow-up map and let $L = \pi^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{X}(E)$.

The line bundle $L$ is not ample because its restriction to $E$ has negative degree. The dual of $L$ is not ample because its retsriction to any curve in $X$ disjoint from $E$ has negative degree.

Now, I claim that $L^{-2},L^{-1},\mathcal{O}_X$ generates $D^b(X)$. This can be proved as follows. I denote by $A$ the full sucategory of $D^b(X)$, closed under taking direct summands, which is generated by $L^{-2}, L^{-1}, \mathcal{O}_X$. Let $F \in D^b(X)$ such that $\mathrm{Ext}^k(a, F) = 0$ for all $a \in A$. I want to prove that $F = 0$ in $D^b(X)$.

Let $x \in X \backslash E$. There exists a line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ through $\pi(x)$, disjoint from $p_0$ so that there is a section $s$ of $L$ whose vanishing locus is exactly $\pi^{-1}(l) \cup E$. Hence, we have an exact sequence:

$$ 0 \rightarrow L^{-1} \stackrel{s}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(l)} \oplus \mathcal{O}_E \rightarrow 0.$$

We deduce that $\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(l)}$ are in $A$. Twisting the above exact sequence by $L^{-1}$, we get that $\mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(l)} \otimes \pi^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)$ and $\mathcal{O}_{E}(-E)$ are also in $A$.

Now, we have an exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(l)} \otimes \pi^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(l)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_x \rightarrow 0.$$

As a consequence, we have $\mathrm{Ext}^k(\mathcal{O}_x, F) = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. In particular, the support of $F$ does not contain $x$.

This is true for all $x \in X \backslash E$ so that the reduced support of $F$ is  included in $E$.

Let $y \in E$. We have an exact sequence on $E$:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E(E) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_y \rightarrow 0.$$

Twisting by $\mathcal{O}_{E}(-E)$, we get an exact sequence on $E$:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E(-E) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_y \rightarrow 0.$$

Pushibg forward by $\mathrm{R} i_*$, we get an exact squence on $X$:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_E(-E) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_y \rightarrow 0.$$

Since we know that $\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\mathcal{O}_E(-E)$ are in $A$, we deduce that $\mathrm{Ext}^k(\mathcal{O}_y, F) = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. But this is true for all $y \in E$. We conclude that the support of $F$ is zero and that $F \simeq 0$ in $D^b(X)$.

Of course it seems difficult to find any condition on $X$ to prevent such a counter-example to appear. Indeed, we'll get a counter-example similar to the one above a soon as we get a birational map $X \rightarrow Y$ which contracts a curve ($Y$ may well be singular!).

Comment: what is the scheme-theoretic support of a complex?

Comment: @YosemiteSam : union of scheme-theoretic support of its cohomology sheaves.

Comment: by scheme-theoretic union you mean taking the intersection of the ideal sheaves? And how do you show that F = i_* G for some G? (or do you have a reference for it?) I think one might be able to use induction on the length of the complex, but I'm not sure I have a rigorous argument.

Comment: Well I thought that the following was kinf of standard. If $F$ is quasi-isomorphic to a sheaf, then its true. Assume that it is true when there are at most $m$ non vanishing cohomology sheaves for $F$. Not let $F'$ with $m+1$ non-vanishing cohomology sheaves.

There is an exact triangle $F'' \rightarrow \mathcal{H}^{i_0}(F') \rightarrow F'$ where $i_0$ is the smallest integer such that $\mathcal{H}^{i}(F') \neq 0$.

Comment: Furthermore, we have $\mathcal{H}^{i}(F'') \simeq \mathcal{H}^{i}(F)$ for all $i>i_0$. By recursion, we know that $F'' = i_*G''$ and $\mathcal{H}^{i_0}(F') = i_* H$ for $H, G'' \in D^b(mE)$.

Furthermore, by adjunction, the map $F'' \rightarrow \mathcal{H}^{i_0}(F')$ lifts to a map $G'' \rightarrow H$. Denote by $G'$ the cokernel of this map. Then, the five lemma shows that $F' \simeq i_* G'$ in $D^b(mE)$.

Comment: I don't follow how you obtain the 'lift' $G'' \to H$. I start with a map $F'' \to H^{i_0}F'$ and by adjunction I get a map $i^*i_* G'' \to H$. But I fail to see how that gives rise to a map $G'' \to H$, since the counit goes $i^*i_* G'' \to G''$ and not the other way around.

Comment: Well there must be a trick to finish the proof, but I don't find it now. In any case, I changed slightly the exposition and proof of my counter-example and I don't need this statement anymore.